# Security -- Subnets

Tags: wireless-networking, security, iot

[Network Segment Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCK2D.jpg)

[image]

This is my setup.  Want to use main and remote guest networks ( on different subnets ) for IOT devices and guest wireless access.  The IOT devices only access from internet ( smartphone ).  How much protection do these give my main network, both from IOT devices and from malicious things on my guest's devices?
My setup works well for my needs, but I am concerned about protecting the computers on my main network.

Answer (score 0):

From other reading here, security is questionable if main computers can be pinged from a computer connected to the different subnets.  Does increase difficulty for malicious intent, but not enough to ensure security.